# Google Sheets - Problem in Macro and JavaScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a macro to write on lines that are not written, for example:

Line number one has something written on it, and the macro writes that thing underneath, basically an automated registration.

I want to do this in Google Spreadsheets (it has a thing that works in JavaScript, I am still learning if you guys also have any tips regarding it... I would be awesome.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getLastRow()` method. It returns the position of the last row that has content. For example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());
```

So you can get the next number of row and write there.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow